# Would defragmentation with free space consolidation result in reduced system speed?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I used the following command to defrag my C hard drive under Windows 8.1:

> defrag C: /V /U /H

It seems the that after defragmentation, my system speed has considerably decreased, as opposed to what I expected. I noticed that the commandline defragment tool also did free space consolidation (as shown by verbose information) though I did not specify an X switch for the command. Is it probable that decreased system speed be caused by disk defragmentation?

Comment: what is now slower? Boot process? this is normal and expected in your case.

Comment: Yes startup speed has considerably decreased. I mean the step after I enter my username to log into the system. Why is this expected and normal @magicandre1981?

Comment: I posted why a defrag makes windows slower and what you can do to make Windows faster.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, read speed of a hard drive should *decrease* by the amount of fragmentation on it. Simply by the fact, that the hard drive head has to move more times and longer ways to load a file -- if the file is not stored on consecutive cluster. Defragmentation reorganizes fragmented files such that they reside in consecutive clusters again thus *increasing* the load speed again. Why it would work the other way around for you I cannot say. It shouldn't be possible.

Note that on SSDs (if you use one) fragmentation is desired for [wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling). You do not want to defrag a SSD!

Defragmentation alone should not cause any decrease in performance. The problem should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to speedup boot, only doing a defragmentation makes it even more worse. Windows includes a advanced prefetcher called ReadyBoot which needs to learn where the files are located on the drive to be effective. Doing a defragmentation destroys this logic. Now the Windows prefetcher need to relearn this.

That#s why you should follow my [boot speedup guide](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262) and use xbootmgr to improve boot times by running this command:

```
xbootmgr -trace boot -prepSystem -verboseReadyBoot
```

This optimizes the HDD by running defrag and doing 6 reboots so that the prefetcher can learn again the new layout of the files.